# How do I print this Awk command so I can output to a new file?

Tags: awk

I have written an awk command and am trying to print it so that I can put the result into a new file, but I'm not sure where to add the print portion of the command.
The awk command does two things, it changes the contents of one cell in a CSV, and removes one column, based on contents of cells.

```
awk -F '\t'  '{sub(/OriginalShotName/,"Tape")} $1 != "TAPE"'
```

What I'm trying to do is get the above to print to terminal so I can use the '>' to pass it into a new file. For example, like this:

```
awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' sample.csv > output.csv
```

Just can't make it work with the more complicated awk.

Comment: It's not clear why you say you "just can't make it work". How does your current attempt fail? Once you have a correct script you can redirect to a file if you want.

Comment: @Corion Fixed. Just didn't copy the last quote mark..

Comment: @tripleee The awk works in that it does what I want it to do, but I don't know where to add the 'print' portion of the command.. I was previously using it in conjunction with a 'while' loop, and saving it to a file that way, like so:
`while read
  do
    awk -F '\t'  '{sub(/OriginalShotName/,"Tape")} $1 != "TAPE"'
  done < $1 > newoutput.csv`

However, I need to change my method, ideally by printing as per original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious should work:

```
awk -F '\t'  '{sub(/OriginalShotName/,"Tape")} $1 != "TAPE"' sample.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: Thank you! Classic case of whooosh. Getting my variables mixed up (in my actual use case the sample.csv was $1, confusing things)

Comment: Please accept the duplicate nomination and untick the accept mark on this answer so I can delete it.